# Make an AD/LDAP query without storing username / password as cleartext

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, lda, ldap-query

Hi I'm creating **Cloudera** environment, and want to share this to other teams. This script should be querying our Active directory server. But unfortunately I don't want to put my password / username inside the script.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM, ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES, AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS, SUBTREE

serverName = 'internal.imsglobal.com'
server = Server(serverName)
conn = Connection(server, read_only=True, user='',password='', auto_bind=True)

person='somebody'

conn.search('dc=internal,dc=mydomain,dc=com', '(&(givenName=*)(sAMAccountName=*{person}*))'.format(person=person), attributes=[ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES])

no_entries = len(conn.entries)
```

What can be done to avoid hardcoding credentials ?
Unfortunately **Cloudera** doesn't allow to use **input** function or anything interactive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dotenv

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Create a .env file that consists of key/values like this:

```
USERNAME=foo
PASSWORD=bar
```

Then load the .env file and access the values.

```
dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), $location_of_.env_file)
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

username = os.getenv("USERNAME")
password = os.getenv("PASSWORD")
```

Comment: @PouyaYousefi How is it not?  As long as the .env isn't committed to a repository and stored securely on the server there is nothing wrong with this implementation.  I guess you're the kind of developer that would trust a cloud service provider to store your keys.

Comment: Or someone who is wary about who can access my home directory.

Comment: @PouyaYousefi That doesn't even make any sense.  The solution allows for you to put the environment file anywhere on the server.  The question wasn't how do I secure my .env it was how do I not have my username and password show up in my source code.  Pay attention.

Comment: Touché. Point taken.